# Unable to convert a JSON file to a ListView

Tags: c#, json, listview

I'm unable to convert a JSON file (opened with OpenFileDialog) to a ListView.

My JSON file looks something like this:

```json
{
    "m_Version": 9,
    "DisplayName": "#STR_EXPANSION_MARKET_CATEGORY_AMMO",
    "Icon": "Deliver",
    "Color": "FBFCFEFF",
    "InitStockPercent": 75.0,
    "Items": [
        {
            "ClassName": "ammo_12gapellets",
            "MaxPriceThreshold": 10,
            "MinPriceThreshold": 5,
            "SellPricePercent": -1,
            "MaxStockThreshold": 500,
            "MinStockThreshold": 1,
            "QuantityPercent": -1,
            "SpawnAttachments": [],
            "Variants": []
        },
        {
            "ClassName": "ammo_12garubberslug",
            "MaxPriceThreshold": 8,
            "MinPriceThreshold": 4,
            "SellPricePercent": -1,
            "MaxStockThreshold": 500,
            "MinStockThreshold": 1,
            "QuantityPercent": -1,
            "SpawnAttachments": [],
            "Variants": []
        }
    ]
}
```

Opening the file and trying to add:

```cs
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
    ofd.Filter = "JSON Files (*.json)|*.json|All files (*.*)|*.*";
    ofd.Multiselect = false;
            
    if(ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        textBox1.Text = ofd.FileName;

        var fileStream = ofd.OpenFile();

        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
        {
            var content = reader.ReadToEnd();
            var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Item>(content);

            listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new string[] { result.ClassName}));
        }
    }
}

public partial class Items
{
    public Item[] Item { get; set; }
}

public partial class Item
{
    [JsonProperty("ClassName")]
    public string ClassName { get; set; }
}
```

When I load the file, it adds something to the first column, however it is just an empty string. How can I get all "Items" to my ListView?

Comment: What  properties do you what to see in your list view? Can you show an example pls?

Comment: I want to see these properties:
            "ClassName": "ammo_12gapellets",
            "MaxPriceThreshold": 10,
            "MinPriceThreshold": 5,
            "SellPricePercent": -1,
            "MaxStockThreshold": 500,
            "MinStockThreshold": 1,
            "QuantityPercent": -1,

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
var content = reader.ReadToEnd();
JArray items= (JArray) JObject.Parse(content)["Items"];
foreach (var item in items)
{
    var namesList= item.Properties().Select(i => i.Value.ToString()).ToArray();
    listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(namesList));
}
```

but IMHO it is better to create DataTable from Json and use it a list view source

```
var content = reader.ReadToEnd();
DataTable items=  JObject.Parse(content)["Items"].ToObject<DataTable>();
```

Comment: That works. However, is there an option to use it like I tried it so I can easily modify these values/properties?

Comment: @CunnertA I am sorry , but what do you mean modify?